# SharePoint Web Service Lists.GetListCollection not returning all lists

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, web-services, sharepoint

I'm using SharePoint's List web service and I tried GetListCollection but it's not returning all the lists. Here's my code (SBALists is my web reference name):

```
Dim Lists As New SBALists.Lists
Lists.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
Dim Result As XmlElement = Lists.GetListCollection
Dim XR As New XmlTextReader(Result.OuterXml, XmlNodeType.Element, Nothing)
Dim DS As New DataSet
DS.ReadXml(XR)
DataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables(0)
```

I also tried passing in my username/password for the credentials but doesn't change the results.

```
Dim Cred As New Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
Lists.Credentials = Cred
```

Any idea why some of the lists aren't returning?

*Edit

[image: Announcements and Links return fine. Project Queue doesn't.]

Comment: Are you expecting to get the Lists from subsites using the GetListCollection method?

Comment: No. The lists I'm trying to get are in the same site, right next to each other. One returns, the other doesn't. I definitely have access to it, I created it.

Comment: Hey @sharmila, I realized after adding the service reference the endpoint address was defaulting to the root site. I had to manually go in the app config and put the correct site. Now the lists are appearing